# Joining csv table and shapefile via ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, csv, attribute-joins

I want to join the attribute table of a shapefile with an externally created csv table via ArcPy.

The format of the columns are:

for attribute table: "Variable1" "Variable2" "Variable3"  "CATCHID"  "Variable 4"...

for csv table:       "CATCHID" "Results1"  "Results2"...

I want to append the attribute table with the contents of the csv table with respect to the "CATCHID" column. Since my csv table doesn't have OID's, I couldn't use JoinField_management function. Hopefully, there's another function named AddJoin_management, it is really useful when used in ModelBuilder, but it is a mess in ArcPy since it requires a table view/feature layer as an input. I made a feature layer, joined two tables and copied the feature layer to a brand new shapefile but this time the names of the columns were changed as "[attributetablename].Variable1", "[attributetablename].Variable2" etc. and they are truncated while creating the new shapefile.

Is there a way to join two tables PROPERLY using ArcPy? (which means I don't want to see the layer names predicate the variable names in the columns.)

```
inputShapefile = r"C:\\input.shp"
inputPath = r"C:\\input.csv"
outputPath = r"C:\\output.shp"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inputShapefile, "tempLayer")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("tempLayer", "CATCHID", inputPath, "CATCHID", "KEEP_COMMON")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("tempLayer", outputPath)
```

Here's the code snippet that I have problem with. This join operation produces a new shapefile that includes "[input].CATCHID" as a column header, for instance. However I need just "CATCHID" as the header.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A question asking for help writing code should include a snippet of your code.  What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of the code you've tried and details of the results when it is run.

Comment: Copy your CSV to an `in_memory` temporary table (which will create the OID) then use `JoinField_management()` to join to your table

Comment: @Midavalo it would have been helpful if you answer it :D